# How to phrase the title in a presentation at an academic interview?

Tags: presentation, titles

When delivering a presentation at an academic interview, what are some keywords which should be included in the title of the presentation? Should the title be in the first person? What are some good examples?

The position I am considering is **assistant professor / lecturer**

I imagine some choices to be:

1. The interview presentation for JACK JAY
2. The presentation for lecturer at Uni Awesome by JACK JAY
3. JACK JAY'S presentation as candidate lecturer at Uni Awesome

Comment: Can you provide us with: i) The position you're applying, and ii) A few samples for us to comment on? Usually, faculty candidates in my institute titled their presentation with their highlighted project or research. Occasionally, a couple may have some catchy titles, but still they never deviated too far away from the key project.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, does this improve the question?

Comment: I simply put the title of the talk, like I would title any other talk. I've never mentioned it as "a presentation by" or "an interview for" in my slides.

Comment: I would never write "Jack Jay, PhD" nor "Dr Jack Jay" in my slides, probably not even my current position, only the department and university where I currently work. But I guess it may depend on the subject area and country: I work in more maths-y stuff and in the UK. I know that in several European countries (by no means in all) titling yourself might seem arrogant, or a bit tacky, or both (again depending on the country).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to include *any* of the proposed titles in your presentation.  They all come across as stilted and affected, and are entirely unnecessary.

Instead, if this is a public presentation, treat it as you would any other such presentation: indicate the title of your talk as you normally would have it, and so on.

If this is the "private" presentation to the faculty, then you should give it a title representing your current and future research interests. You don't need to say "what" the presentation is for—again, the location of the talk should be sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

Just throw it out here. Perhaps others can upload their suggested topic slide as well? That would be fun.

I don't like to appear to be overly kissing-up, so I'll opt for toning down the university. My talk would have been broadcasted and posted for a while at the institute so the audience should know why they are here. So I'll just focus on up-playing my topic and who I am.

It'd be prudent to clarify with the hiring committee chair on the format and topics to be covered. But beyond that, just be at ease with the format stuff; focus on the contents. Be very, very certain that you cover just enough background to show you can think in breadth and depth, explain what your research questions are, and present your methods and results in alignment with your questions, and state briefly the implication. For job talk, leave a few minutes to elaborate how your work can grow into your career path, and highlight potential synergistic collaboration with some hot areas that your target institute is good at (e.g. "I'll also love to collaborate with the specialists at your Marine Dietary Assessment Center to cast a more critical look at the diet-obesity association.") You'll need to read their website/reports up on that. Find some friends, colleagues, and mentors to sit in your practice sessions.

Best of luck!

[image]